# Why is performance of ImageIdentify so different between dog and cat?

Tags: machine-learning

I am playing Mathematica 11's new `ImageIdentify` function and is really impressed by its capability. But I found a problem, `ImageIdentify`'s performance is quite different for different kind of object.

For example, for dogs

[image]

This is really great!!!

However, cat...

[image]

Hey, are we looking at same kind of cat faces???

Why such a huge difference? What is behind `ImageIdentify` that cause such a difference?

Comment: Likely that the training set had a better defined dog database. From my experience this would make some sense as people are generally much more concerned with dog breeds while cats are just... cats...

Comment: @user6014 I don't have a pet. But I still think this is unfair for cat... Poor cat...